# Refresh a TAB of a Tabhost listadapter from within a list of another adapter

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad English.....

i need refresh a TabHost (Tab2) from a ListAdapter include in this tab2....

I have a TabHost and in tab2 i have an ListAdapter and in this i have other listAdapter. i need refresh this tab2 from this second ListAdapter.

It is the plan:

```
[ Tab 1 ]    [ Tab 2 ]
------------------------------------------
[05:00 am] - in first ListAdapter
  ------------------------------------
    [ node 1 ] in second ListAdapter
    [ node 2 ] in second ListAdapter

[06:00 am] - in first ListAdapter
  ------------------------------------
    [ node 1 ] in second ListAdapter
    [ node 2 ] in second ListAdapter
    [ node 3 ] in second ListAdapter

[06:30 am] - in first ListAdapter
  ------------------------------------
    [ node 1 ] in second ListAdapter
```

If I click in buttons on Second ListAdapter I show a custom dialog and in this a need refresh the Tab2. For make for example the node 2 in 06:00 am not show more.

How i can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you want to refresh the data in a ListView you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you have modified the contents of your list objects.

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I did not understand. I have an inside another adapter and the need to update the first second, or update the child's father. example, say I have an adapter times (06:00, 07:00,08:00) and each time I have another adapter with a set of tasks. when I perform a task I need to remove it from the list. I need this to access the listview which is inside one of the times and have it update. but how to access it from inside the method getView?